# D3 bar chart not parsing csv

Tags: javascript, parsing, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to build a basic, responsive bar chart with data loaded from a CSV. My chart isn't reading the CSV and gives me NaNs. [Here's a screenshot of what my chart looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKz5v.png) Here is my current code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var url = "data/data.csv", 
    margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 10},
    width = parseInt(d3.select('#chart').style('width'), 10),
    width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200, // placeholder
    barHeight = 20,
    spacing = 5,
    total = d3.format('n');

// scales and axes
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([0, 4000]); // hard-coding this because I know the data

var y = d3.scale.ordinal();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .ticks(3);

// create the chart
var chart = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
    .style('width', (width + margin.left + margin.right) + 'px')
  .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + [margin.left, margin.top] + ')');

d3.csv(url).row(function(d) {
    d.total = +d.total;
    d.name = +d.name;

    return d;
}).get(function(err, data) {
    // sort
    data = _.sortBy(data, 'total').reverse();

    // set y domain
    y.domain(d3.range(data.length))
        .rangeBands([0, data.length * barHeight]);

    // set height based on data
    height = y.rangeExtent()[1];
    d3.select(chart.node().parentNode)
        .style('height', (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + 'px')

    // render the chart

    // add top and bottom axes
    chart.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis top')
        .call(xAxis.orient('top'));

    chart.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis bottom')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(xAxis.orient('bottom'));

    var bars = chart.selectAll('.bar')
        .data(data)
      .enter().append('g')
        .attr('class', 'bar')
        .attr('transform', function(d, i) { return 'translate(0,'  + y(i) + ')'; });

    bars.append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'background')
        .attr('height', y.rangeBand())
        .attr('width', width);

    bars.append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'total')
        .attr('height', y.rangeBand())
        .attr('width', function(d) { return x(d.total); })

    bars.append('text')
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
        .attr('class', 'name')
        .attr('y', y.rangeBand() - 5)
        .attr('x', spacing);


    bars.append('line')
        .attr('class', 'median')
        .attr('x1', x(median))
        .attr('x2', x(median))
        .attr('y1', 1)
        .attr('y2', y.rangeBand() - 1);
});

// resize
d3.select(window).on('resize', resize); 

function resize() {
    // update width
    width = parseInt(d3.select('#chart').style('width'), 10);
    width = width - margin.left - margin.right;

    // resize the chart
    x.range([0, width]);
    d3.select(chart.node().parentNode)
        .style('height', (y.rangeExtent()[1] + margin.top + margin.bottom) + 'px')
        .style('width', (width + margin.left + margin.right) + 'px');

    chart.selectAll('rect.background')
        .attr('width', width);

    chart.selectAll('rect.total')
        .attr('width', function(d) { return x(d.total); });

    // update axes
    chart.select('.x.axis.top').call(xAxis.orient('top'));
    chart.select('.x.axis.bottom').call(xAxis.orient('bottom'));

}

// highlight code blocks
hljs.initHighlighting();

</script>
```

Here's the data:

```
name, total
Brian, 1514
Frankie, 1439
Jeffery, 1615
Jerry, 685
Kenneth, 3233
Michael, 116
Roy, 817
Timothy, 2184
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a couple of issues with your code and data:

For the issues with the data, you can either clean up the rows by removing the spaces, eg:

```
name,total
Brian,1514
Frankie,1439
Jeffery,1615
Jerry,685
Kenneth,3233
Michael,116
Roy,817
Timothy,2184
```

Or you can reference them in your code using the [] notation, eg:

```
d[' total'] = +d[' total'];
```

d3 is adding the leading space to the attribute name for each record.  When you reference the attributes as d.total, it's returning undefined and undefined coerced to a number is NaN.

Eg. data[0]['total'] is undefined but data[0][' total'] has "1514" as you'd expect.  Removing the spaces from the data is the easiest way of dealing with this.

In your code, you're doing this:

```
d.name = +d.name;
```

This will translate the name value into NaN, as it's a text string beginning with an alpha character, so javascript doesn't know how to coerce it to a number.

You're also referencing a variable named median which isn't declared in your code.

I've created a jsfiddle to help: http://jsfiddle.net/BenLyall/eh1r6j2e/12/

Note: I've changed the d3.csv... line to work with an element in the DOM to store the data.

Comment: It was my spacing in the CSV. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making name into Number
below code

```
d3.csv(url).row(function(d) {
    d.total = +d.total;
    d.name = +d.name;

    return d;
})
```

remove conversion of name.Okay